# Ideas to classify shipping addresses

Tags: classification

I have a dataset of addresses for a bunch of users. I need to classify an address into residential/commercial or office/educational.
Moreover, every user has multiple addresses. So every user has a set of addresses.

There's no direct labelled data.
What I do have are tags for some of the the users eg: Student, Parent, Gender

Some intuitive thoughts:
One might expect to have an Educational address in an address set of a Student.
Every user will probably have at least 1 Residential address in his/her address set.

But how do I use this data to create a classifier?
Are there any existing techniques to solve this kind of problem?
Any particular areas/concepts in Machine Learning that I should take a look at?

Comment: For "educational", do you mean " on campus" address?  If so, and you are only looking e.g. at US addresses, then a naive approach might be easiest = obtain/compile a database of campus post/zip codes

Comment: @P.Windridge Hey! Yeah by 'Educational' I do mean 'on campus' addresses. I'm working on Indian addresses. Yup I agree the naive approach you mentioned is probably a good place to start but I would still need a different approach for the 'Residential' and 'Commercial/Office' addresses.